# Why can't I do vars(<Namesapce>)[subscript]

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, idioms

In Python, Why can't I convert use a subscript on the vars() of a Namespace in one line?

What is the idiomatic pythonic way?

i.e:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="test parameters")
parser.add_argument('param1', nargs='?', help="param1")
args = parser.parse_args()
if vars(args)['param1'] is None:
    <do something special>
else:
    <do something else special>
```

Above doesn't work - runtime error.

Works find if I change line `vars(args)['param1']` to:

```
dict = vars(args)
param1 = dict['param1']
```

Comment: If that's an error, then that implies that the result of `vars(args)` doesn't return a dictionary for you.  Also, avoid the use of `dict` as a variable name since that shadows the built-in `dict` function.

Comment: @snowbound what is the runtime error? I didn't get any error. I am assumming you have overwritten `vars()` with some other function somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @Makoto for the `dict` tip.

Comment: I ran the code again. No issues this time. You were right @AnandSKumar, I did overwrite it later on :P  How do I close this issue